# Windows 10 Taskbar not clickable

Tags: windows-10

My windows 10 taskbar recieved a couple of problems since a couple weeks now. I think it started after some update.

1. All my shortcuts can not be clicked with mouse right click. Nothing happens.
2. I cannot click on the clock to view my calendar with left click.
3. I can't open my notifications with left click.

Check out the screenshot.
[image]

I can't find a fix for this. Anyone knows how to do it and what is going on? Thanks!

Comment: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.  Run (1) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth . Then (2) SFC /SCANNOW   .   Allow to complete, restart and test. This initial Windows 10 repair often works.

Comment: @John What does it repair? May the command have some other implications?

Comment: It repairs local files that may have been damaged. DISM is not a Repair Install. DISM is the first thing to try. After the DISM sequence above, and if that fails, run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link.

Comment: @john Thanks, i ll try it out...

Comment: It appears you have a Start Menu replacement installed?  Is that indeed the case?

Comment: @Ramhound No, it is just the dark theme of windows 10

Comment: I was talking about the hamburger button on the taskbar.

Comment: @Ramhound Are you refering to Nr. 3 on the screenshot? What do you mean by hamburger?

Comment: The leftmost icon in your screenshot

Comment: @Ramhound Thats the shortcut for eclipse :)

Comment: Did you run DISM and did that help?  Did you run the Repair Install and did that help?

Comment: @john i ran both cmd commands. didn't work

Comment: When nothing suggested here works, you will need to back up your data and documents and reinstall Windows.

Comment: @John do you see that edge icon over there? I dont use edge and i dont want to. I think its an intended windows "bug", because I cant right click on it and remove it

Comment: I do not have any on any of machines with Start, or the Taskbar and that is with old Edge, new Edge or Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working again after following the fix suggested in the following link [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/taskbar-not-working-on-windows-10/01e8899a-1660-4160-a62f-35e17b753ee7). The powershell command that fixed it was:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers |Where-Object {$_.InstallLocation -like "*SystemApps*"} | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```